# Sending Push notifications to iOS devices using PushSharp and C#

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I have been struggling to get push notifications to send from a C# console application. I have a working p12 certificate from apple's development website and i also have the device token for the device i want to send the notification to. Below is the code i am using to try and send the notification. I am using an older version of PushSharp (2.2.1.0) as I am using the same console application to send android push notifications which works 100%.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PushSharp;
using PushSharp.Android;
using PushSharp.Apple;
using PushSharp.Core;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace PushNotificationServiceTradeway
{
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var push = new PushBroker();
        push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
        push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
        push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
        push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
        push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
        push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;


        //Registering the Apple Service and sending an iOS Notification
        var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("Certificate");
        push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, ""));
        push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                                   .ForDeviceToken("Phone_Token")
                                   .WithAlert("Hello World!")
                                   .WithBadge(7));

        push.StopAllServices();

    }


    static void DeviceSubscriptionChanged(object sender,
string oldSubscriptionId, string newSubscriptionId, INotification notification)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(notification);
    }

    //this even raised when a notification is successfully sent
    static void NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(notification);
    }

    //this is raised when a notification is failed due to some reason
    static void NotificationFailed(object sender,
    INotification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(notificationFailureException);
    }

    //this is fired when there is exception is raised by the channel
    static void ChannelException
        (object sender, IPushChannel channel, Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }

    //this is fired when there is exception is raised by the service
    static void ServiceException(object sender, Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }

    //this is raised when the particular device subscription is expired
    static void DeviceSubscriptionExpired(object sender,
    string expiredDeviceSubscriptionId,
        DateTime timestamp, INotification notification)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(notification);
    }

    //this is raised when the channel is destroyed
    static void ChannelDestroyed(object sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sender);
    }

    //this is raised when the channel is created
    static void ChannelCreated(object sender, IPushChannel pushChannel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pushChannel);
    }

}
}
```

But when i run the application to send the notification it hangs and times out after a minute with the following error in the console

System.Net.Sockets.Socketexception (0x80004005) a connection attempt failed bacause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.172.232.45:2196
    at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, int32 port)
    at Pushsharp.Apple.FeedbackService.Run(ApplePushChannelSetings, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    at PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService.(ApplePushService)c_AnonStorey0.()m_1(object state)

Any help or advice on how to fix/solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending to production or sandbox? Your version of pushsharp may not be compatible to apples new certificate names.

Comment: Thanks for the reply derpirscher. Yes I've double checked and it is a sandbox certificate, but ill do some more research to see if the new certificates are compatible with older pushsharp versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the fix, it was the firewall settings at my company blocking access to Apple's push notification servers.

Comment: hey greg..can u please share the working code for this..cos m not able to get it working

Comment: @Lakshay Hey, fortunately this was only a network error where the address was blocked by our network. This code should work fine but we still haven't solved the problem with the certificates not working. Ill post here if we get it working.